# Description from one sheet into comment of another sheet in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

what i have an excel with incoming on one sheet and code descriptions on another i would like to auto create a Comment displaying the description of the incomming codes or is this possible.

ex.

```
"sheet 1"                   -------------------
serial   | Symptom Code     |"Comment Box"    |
xx1234   | LX1, LC45 ------ |Machine Broken   | 
                            |Physical Damage  |   
                            -------------------    
"sheet 2"
Code     | Description
LX1      | Machine Broken
LC45     | Physical Damage
```

Hopefully thats a good example of what im looking for my reputation isnt high enough to insert pictures if you can halp me thank you very much

Comment: Is it necessary that it be in a "standard" comment (cell corner flag that opens the comment), or could it be embedded in the cell, itself (visible if you look at the cell contents), or in an adjacent cell?

Comment: good question. unfortunately i use the cell in different formulas and the sheet is pretty full. aesthetically adding to another adjacent cell wouldnt work. so worst case scenario adjacent cell but not prefered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say *Sheet1* is like:

[image]

and *Sheet2* is like:

[image]

Then the following macro will lookup the descriptions and add them as Comments to the **B** column cells in *Sheet1*

```
Sub CommentMaker()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, N1 As Long, N2 As Long
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String
    Dim i1 As Long, i2 As Long
    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    N1 = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    N2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i1 = 2 To N1
        s1 = sh1.Cells(i1, "B").Text
        For i2 = 2 To N2
            s2 = sh2.Cells(i2, "A").Text
            If s1 = s2 Then
                sh1.Cells(i1, "B").ClearComments
                sh1.Cells(i1, "B").AddComment sh2.Cells(i2, "B").Text
            End If
        Next i2
    Next i1

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice (I upvoted), but in the question, each serial number can have several comma-delimited symptom codes.  If I'm reading your solution correctly, it clears, then stores a single comment.  If that's correct, can you modify it to recognize the symptom codes within the string in the sheet1 B cell and append multiple comment texts?

Comment: This is very useful and i appreciate this i actually have somehwere elsei can use this but what fixer1234 said was right on i will take a look at the code myself but i am fairly new to VBA so any help if very appreciated Thank you Very much for your help. i tried to upvote but i have been thwarted by the low rep new user affect again lol so virtual upvote.

Comment: @Mark ..........I will also look at parsing multiple symptom codes.